# jQuery Image Crossfade not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, cycle, cross-fade

Hello what is wrong with our jQuery image crossfade set-up!?
http://tips.techmatemn.com/

HTML

```
<div class="hero-cycler">
    <img class="active" alt="Tips qualified Client 1" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/img/hero-bk-1.jpg">
    <img alt="Tips qualified Client 2" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/img/hero-bk-2.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hero-cycler{position:relative;}
.hero-cycler img{position:absolute;z-index:1}
.hero-cycler img.active{z-index:3}
```

SCRIPT

```
<script> // homepage client images
function cycleImages(){
      var $active = $('.hero-cycler .active');
      var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('.hero-cycler img:first');
      $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
      $active.fadeOut(1500,function(){//fade out the top image
      $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
          $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
      });
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
// run every 7s
setInterval('cycleImages()', 7000);
})
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you seeing? What exactly doesn't work? Are there any errors? Also, if you're only cycling between two images, you could significantly simplify this.

Comment: We will have more images once we get this working. I see the first image. My guess is the script is not working, because the images are not cycling.

Comment: Check for errors in the browser console, that's always a good place to start. I'll stick this in a fiddle and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the way you call the function. Your `setInterval` uses the string parameter which is depreciated and generally not recommended. Use the standard method shown below to correctly run the function.

Change `setInterval('cycleImages()', 7000);` to `setInterval(cycleImages, 7000);`

Full working copy with generic filler images:

```js
function cycleImages() {
  var $active = $('.hero-cycler .active');
  var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('.hero-cycler img:first');
  $next.css('z-index', 2); //move the next image up the pile
  $active.fadeOut(1500, function() { //fade out the top image
    $active.css('z-index', 1).show().removeClass('active'); //reset the z-index and unhide the image
    $next.css('z-index', 3).addClass('active'); //make the next image the top one
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // run every 7s
  setInterval(cycleImages, 7000);
})
```

```css
.hero-cycler {
  position: relative;
}
.hero-cycler img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1
}
.hero-cycler img.active {
  z-index: 3
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero-cycler">
  <img class="active" alt="Tips qualified Client 1" src="https://unsplash.it/300/200/?image=0">
  <img alt="Tips qualified Client 2" src="https://unsplash.it/300/200/?image=1">
</div>
```

(A quick check of the browser console would have shown you the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: cycleImages is not defined` which would have been very helpful to include in your question)